# Is my ModPagespeedSlowFileLatencyUs setting ignored?

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, pagespeed

I have put `ModPagespeedSlowFileLatencyUs 1500000` on the top level of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf`, as recommended by various posts, but I'm still getting PageSpeed error messages like the following:

> Slow read operation on file […]: 66.881ms; configure SlowFileLatencyUs to change threshold\n

All the messages are about read operations more than 50 ms, so I suspect that [the default](https://github.com/pagespeed/mod_pagespeed/commit/97906ac7555a08739d3fe9bdc6628134683a05ec#diff-c07a8c7aa5d090e591e9ddf3ff21ee97) is being used instead of my setting.

The PageSpeed admin configuration page also reports `SlowFileLatencyUs (asflt) 1500000`.

Using version 1.9.32.11-7550 (latest on RedHat).

Comment: Did you restart the webserver?

Comment: @symcbean It's a long time ago, but I'm well aware of the need to do so, so I'll assume I did :)

Comment: @l0b0 what did you do in order to fix this? I'm having the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely no idea @Jaec, sorry. I haven't worked with Apache for the last three years; I don't even remember asking this.

Comment: Thnaks anyway, @l0b0.